# How to format URL in android

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

I am working on URL link, but only half of the link is blue (clickable) shown in image[image]

The url i am using -                 String newfullurl = "https://myappnametest.herokuapp.com/predict?{"+""arr""+":[114.4756,31.57832,4.698017,1.834955,1.433942,1.388775,6.730856,12.19739,7.460399,4.807888,115.51131,69.19083,504.85333,186.9337,42.39501,31.519505,56.937508,39.56942]}";

How can I get full link, which is clickable so i get data from API

Answer (score 1):

You can try `URLEncoder.encode(newfullurl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`